# Unity Ctrl + Alt + Del set default value to 'Lock'

Tags: unity, lock-screen, logout

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> I get a dialog with two buttons: Log-out and Lock.

I spent a significant portion of my time working on Windows workstations, and the default there is Lock. It is a habit, that when I want to leave my computer I lock it by quickly pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It's frustrating that in unity the default value of the dialog box is Logout, and I end up logging out and sometimes unsaved work is lost.

How do I make the default value Lock instead of Log-out?

Comment: Just so you know, Ctrl-Alt-L locks.

Comment: Just a tip: Super-L works on both platforms.

Answer (score 12):

You can override the default shortcut by creating your custom shortcut for this purpose.

- Go to **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** ->
  **Custom Shortcuts**
- Add a shortcut with any name with following  command in command
  box

  ```
  qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
  ```
- Now click on this newly created shortcut and assign it
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- Click on `Reassign` if popup  window is appearing with  warning message about  shortcut conflict.

---

To restore the default behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> shortcut

- Delete  your custom shortcut.
- Select ***System*** in left column of shortcut setting window.
- Select `logout` shortcut  and assign  it  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>